# How to run the docker commands from python?

Tags: python, docker

I want to run a set of docker commands from python.
I tried creating a script like below and run the script from python using paramiko ssh_client to connect to the machine where the docker is running:

```
#!/bin/bash

   # Get container ID
   container_id="$(docker ps | grep hello | awk '{print $1}')"

   docker exec -it $container_id sh -c "cd /var/opt/bin/ && echo $1 && 
   echo $PWD && ./test.sh -q $1"
```

But `docker exec ...` never gets executed.

So I tried to run the below python script below, directly in the machine where the docker is running:
    import subprocess

```
docker_run = "docker exec 7f34a9c1b78f /bin/bash -c \"cd 
/var/opt/bin/ && ls -a\"".split()
subprocess.call(docker_run, shell=True)
```

I get a message: "Usage:    docker COMMAND..."

But I get the expected results if I run the command

> > docker exec 7f34a9c1b78f /bin/bash -c "cd /var/opt/bin/ && ls -a"
> >     directly in the machine

How to run multiple docker commands from the python script? Thanks!

Comment: This `container_id="$(docker ps | grep <container> | awk '{print $1}')"` doesn't look right.  I think you forgot to replace `<container>` with the actual container.

Comment: When I ran the actual script I added the actual container. Let me modify the question so it is clear.

Comment: Use [`docker-py`](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) instead of hardcoding all of this subprocess work.  I use it very frequently and have been happy with it

Comment: I am trying to avoid docker module, as I don't want to install anything new on the system. Also, I am not sure if the container is exposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake in your call to `subprocess.call`. `subprocess.call` expects a command with a series of parameters. You've given it a list of parameter pieces.

This code:

```
docker_run = "docker exec 7f34a9c1b78f /bin/bash -c \"cd 
/var/opt/bin/ && ls -a\"".split()
subprocess.call(docker_run, shell=True)
```

Runs this:

```
subprocess.call([
   'docker', 'exec', '7f34a9c1b78f', '/bin/bash', '-c', 
   '"cd', '/var/opt/bin/', '&&', 'ls', '-a"'
 ], shell=True)
```

Instead, I believe you want:

```
subprocess.call([
   'docker', 'exec', '7f34a9c1b78f', '/bin/bash', '-c', 
   '"cd /var/opt/bin/ && ls -a"' # Notice how this is only one argument.
 ], shell=True)
```

You might need to tweak that second call. I suspect you don't need the quotes (`'cd /var/opt/bin/ && ls -a'` might work instead of `'"cd /var/opt/bin/ && ls -a"'`), but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Tried below 3 ways, still get the "docker usage" message       subprocess.call(['docker', 'exec', '7f34a9c1b78f', '/bin/bash', '-c', 'cd /opt/bin/ && ls -a'], shell=True)
subprocess.call(['docker', 'exec', '7f34a9c1b78f', '/bin/bash', '-c', '"cd /opt/bin/ && ls -a"'], shell=True)
subprocess.call(['docker', 'exec', '7f34a9c1b78f', '/bin/bash', '-c', '\"cd /opt/bin/ && ls -a\"'], shell=True)

Answer (score 2):

Following are a few methods worked:
Remove double quotes:

```
subprocess.call([
    'docker', 'exec', '7f34a9c1b78f', '/bin/bash', '-c', 
    'cd /opt/teradata/tdqgm/bin/ && ./support-archive.sh -q 6b171e7a-7071-4975-a3ac-000000000241'
    ])
```

If you are not sure of how the command should be split up to pass it as an argument of subprocess method, `shlex` module:
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shlex.html#shlex.split